# New Sound Devices Show up in Hardware But not Input or Output

Tags: 11.10, sound

If I insert a new audio device it shows up under the Hardware Tab of Sound Settings:

[image]

However, I don't see it as an option in Input or Output Tab:

[image]

Comment: Another oddity is that when I click "Test Speakers" with Analog Stereo Duplex selected it shows 7 channels to test instead of just "left right"

Answer (score 2):

Discovered a workaround. If I open up a terminal and run `killall pulseaduio` (without elevated privileges) the device then appears in the output tab once pulseaudio restarts itself.

Clearly not a solution or an ideal workaround.

Comment: Looks like a regression https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-media/+bug/775345

Answer (score 0):

Try to change Profile for your device under the Hardware Tab of Sound Settings. 
For Plantronics it mast be "Analog Output + Mono Input" instead of "Analog Stereo Duplex"

Comment: That isn't an option, if I change it to Analog Stereo Output it still doesn't show up though.

Comment: Look for some profile in the list, which include Input option, not only Output