# USB Speakers are recognised, but can't be selected in sound menu

Tags: sound, usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New Sound Devices Show up in Hardware But not Input or Output](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112303/new-sound-devices-show-up-in-hardware-but-not-input-or-output)

I have USB Speakers that used to work with Ubuntu. In 12.10 I can see them through lsusb...

```
Bus 006 Device 006: ID 0e6a:0310 Megawin Technology Co., Ltd
```

... And I can see it in the "hardware" tab in the sound menu...

[image: Hardware tab]

... But I can't select them in the Output tab.

[image: Output tab]

Comment: Guys, anyone? I'm seriously clueless here =/

Answer (score 2):

try this..

open youe terminal and type

```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-sound-applet
```

it will uninstall the gnome-sound-applet and reinstall it .

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of [New Sound Devices Show up in Hardware But not Input or Output](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112303/new-sound-devices-show-up-in-hardware-but-not-input-or-output) and it looks like a bug which should be reported here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs